# Making a compiled constructor expression with just the Type of the type

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, lambda

I've been playing around, partially reinventing wheels so that I can understand how proper wheels spin round.

Consider this generic function for compiling and returning the default constructor of a type.

```
public static Func<TConcrete> Creator<TConcrete>()
{
    // All checking removed for brevity
    var ctor = typeof(TConcrete).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TConcrete>>(Expression.New(ctor));
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

I believe this will return me a nice typed delegate that I can use to instantiate the passed type.

Now consider, I want a function that would do this for a set of different types, how would I go about that? I was thiking along the lines of ...

```
public static IEnumerable<Delegate> Creators(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        var lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<????>>(Expression.New(ctor));
        yield return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the `????` this is where I got stuck. Is there a way to do this or is my approach just flawed?

Comment: How does the code look like that calls the `Creators` method and uses the returned delegates?

Comment: @dtb, that code doesen't actually exist, my program actually has a function that takes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, Type>>` to pass associations between Interfaces and Concrete Implementations but, I thought that was superfluous to my actual question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the non-generic overload in combination with `MakeGenericType`:

```
var lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<????>>(Expression.New(ctor));
```

Should become:

```
var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var lamda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, Expression.New(ctor));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a different [`Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx) call which takes the delegate type as a `Type`:

```
Type delegateType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Expression.New(ctor));
yield return lambda.Compile();
```

Note that this overload of `Lambda` returns the non-generic [`LambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) type rather than `Expression<TDelegate>` - but it still exposes a [`Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) method which returns `Delegate`, which is all you need here. Basically it's just avoiding some of the compile-time type checking you benefit from in your "known delegate type" code.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I should have spent some time reading my intellisense there.